# How to use awk to do file copy. Copy using split in awk not working

Tags: unix, awk

I am missing something subtle. I tried running below command but it didn't work. Can you please help .

```
ls | awk '{ split($1,a,".gz")} {cp " "   $1 " "  a[1]".gz"}'
```

Although when i am trying to print it is showing copy command.

```
ls | awk '{ split($1,a,".gz")} {print "cp" " "   $1 " "  a[1]".gz"}'
```

Not sure where the problem is. Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Try giving an explanation.

Comment: in your first line, `cp` is an undefined variable. Are you trying to execute a cmd like `cp file.txt file.gz` ? Agree with @fedorqui, please add sample `ls` listings and expected result from that list. Good luck.

Comment: Hi fedorqui/shellter , this is out of ls 20140306_ABC_HJI_20140306.gz_RD_20140307_053725_3355744   20140306_ABC_XYZ_20140306.gz_RD_20140307_053725_3355743
20140306_ABC_MRQ_20140306.gz_RD_20140307_053725_3355741        20140306_ABC_TGR_20140306.gz_RD_20140307_053725_3355745
20140306_ABC_HVM_20140306.gz_RD_20140307_053725_3355742
as you can see i tried splillting the output based on ".gz" and i would like to cp  20140306_ABC_TGR_20140306.gz_RD_20140307_053725_3355745 20140306_ABC_TGR_20140306.gz. Thats is what cp inside is doing.

Comment: awk is not shell just like C is not shell. You can't call shell commands directly from awk just like you can't call shell commands directly from C. Also, awk is a tool for manipulating the content of text files. shell is a an environment from which to call tools and manipulate files and processes so it's not obvious what you're trying to do and why you're trying to do it the way you posted. Update your question with an explanation of what you want to do and some sample input + expected output.

Comment: Please learn to edit important information like this into the main body of your question. As is, it's incomprehensible. Use `edit` link at bottom of your question, copy paste your data, and use the `{}` tool at the top left to format so text stays separate on each line. Note that you can see a "preview" of your change in the display below the input box. Good luck.

Comment: @EdMorton, you can call shell commands directly from awk as well as c. `system(cmd)` for both will execute a shell command.

Comment: Of course, I didn't say you couldn't call `system()` to call the shell to execute a shell command - "I said You can't call shell commands **directly** from awk..." which is relevant because that's what the OP was trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using `awk` at all?  Try:

```
for f in *; do cp "$f" "${f%.gz*}.gz"; done
```

Comment: +1 for deciphering the OPs comment about what he was trying to do! I looked at it several times and just could not figure out what he was trying to tell us.

Answer (score 6):

To summarize some of the comments and point out what's wrong with the first example:

```
ls | awk '{ split($1,a,".gz")} {cp " "   $1 " "  a[1]".gz"}'
                                ^ unassigned variable
```

The `cp` defaults to "" and is not treated as the program `cp`.  If you do the following in a directory with one file, `test.gz_monkey`, you'll see why:

```
ls | awk '{split($1,a,".gz"); cmd=cp " " $1 " " a[1] ".gz"; print ">>" cmd "<<"  }'
```

results in

```
>> test.gz_monkey test.gz<<
  ^ the space here is because cp was "" when cmd was assigned
```

Notice that you can separate statements with a `;` instead of having two action blocks.  Awk does support running commands in a subshell - one of which is `system`, another is `getline`.  With the following changes, your concept can work:

```
ls | awk '{split($1,a,".gz"); cmd="cp  "$1" "a[1]".gz"; system(cmd) }'
                                   ^ notice cp has moved inside a string
```

Another thing to notice - `ls` isn't a good choice for only finding files in the current directory.  Instead, try `find`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.gz_*" | awk '{split($1,a,".gz"); cmd="cp  "$1" "a[1]".gz"; system(cmd) }'
```

while personally, I think something like the following is more readable:

```
find . -type f -name "*.gz_*" | awk '{split($1,a,".gz"); system(sprintf( "cp %s %s.gz", $1, a[1])) }'
```